# How important is it for a child to have a limited number of caregivers?

Tags: developmental-psychology, parenting

In the context of instituational child care, I have heard that a child needs to form an attachment with a limited number of people to function properly. However, now when I tried to find some sources for this claim, I have only found studies which say

1. It may be connected to the simple time and energy a caregiver has per child ([Schipper, 2006](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/3878403.pdf?casa_token=OwOBO7GGnIsAAAAA:CrGdxzoKBqbygyAaow4G4-umQ8HnAR_TXnG6oMJy9aaniGwWUDB77jmxoUIDABDYme_T0SsRVZnKLbjRuxCv_4shCvCBqZ2XX9sepsQeLZVRgozfBLuR); [Palmerus, 1991](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/0300443910710110?casa_token=nH-5kOxW-sUAAAAA:iOSUPqsBJF3f5PjeQ8QqW4is5pw7aoETLr3FXnGriISxQDqh23o9Th6dhA0Orr_OvLBAotUfBlTjng))
2. Some evidence [suggests](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/insight-therapy/201710/nonparental-daycare-what-the-research-tells-us) quality institutional daycare of preschool children doesn't disrupt their parental attachment.
3. Polyamorous families [don't seem](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/340422823_Polyamorous_Parenting_in_Contemporary_Research_Developments_and_Future_Directions) to be a disadvantage in raising healthy children

So is the number of important caregivers something important?

Comment: Related but not duplicate: https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/24789/7604